# Only using OpenStreetMap in this leaflet map?

Tags: html, leaflet, mapbox

I'm new to creating maps with map layers and tiles, so please bear with me.

So I'm working on a map to display points, and I've read that `OpenStreetMap` is free, and `mapbox` isn't. For this reason we only want to use `OpenStreetMap`.

This HTML example draws a map and plots points, but the code says it uses both  technologies. Here's the code.

Two questions:

Is it correct to say that both mapbox and OpenStreetMap are essentially the same thing as they both offer tiles used to draw maps?

I would like to remove mapbox and only use OpenStreetMap in this example. Is this possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet - Points</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-dsdfsdjflsdfjsljfsdl+asfsfsflskjfsld==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/wrwrwerwer+wwerwrwerwer+dasdasdas==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 1200px;
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script src="points.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([18.4148, -66.1241], 11);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.qweqeqweqweqwe.qeqqqwe', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);
    L.geoJSON([bicycleRental], {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                radius: 7,
                fillColor: "#ff7800",
                color: "#000",
                weight: 1,
                opacity: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.8
            });
        }
    }).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use OpenStreetMap tiles you have to set this:

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: ['a','b','c']
}).addTo(map);
```

Instead of mapbox servers. Check the example on the Leaflet's home https://leafletjs.com/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) is a great resource for finding basemaps. When you select one, you can simply copy the JavaScript provided. Most are free to use with attribution.